# How can I get the first letters of each word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get the first letter of each word in an array and log these first letters  to the console.

These are the words:

```
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"];


function getNames(names) {
    // 
}
```

Comment: loop through and use String.charAt(0)

Comment: This seems like a homework task... What have you tried so far?

Comment: just function names(names) {
    console.log(names[0])
}

Comment: @NickParsons is right, this is simple task, please learn some basic tutorials, and try googling before asking question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charAt(0)` for each word in array. You can use simple `forEach()` loop for that:

```js
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"];
function getNames(names){
  names.forEach(item => console.log(item.charAt(0)));
}

getNames(names);
```

You can also go with traditional way of `for` loop if you are new in using loops:

```js
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"];
function getNames(names){
   for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
      console.log(names[i].charAt(0))
   }
}

getNames(names);
```

> Also note that the function name and variable name in your case cannot be same which you are using as **names** as it will conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the first letter by using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the first letter.

```js
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"],
    result = names.map(([c]) => c);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array map:

```js
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"];
var result = names.map(current=>{
    return current[0];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as this is not supported in IE7. `.charAt(pos)` should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"],

result = names.map(name => name[0]);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const names = arr => arr.forEach(s => console.log(s[0]));
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as this is not supported in IE7. `.charAt(pos)` should be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter through the array using a for loop, and then push the first letter to a filtered array and then return that.

```
var names = ["Vincent", "Charlotte", "Nandi", "Eiske", "Joachim", "Angelo", "Paul", "Chantal", "Olaf", "Inge", "Rogier", "Michael", "Ramon", "Carolien", "Johan", "Bianca", "Rene", "Yulia", "Bram", "Anneloes", "Kirsten", "Roel", "Gökhan", "Annemiek", "Lisette", "Menno", "Rene", "Erik", "Robin", "Frank", "Anton", "Maks", "Rob", "Floor", "Bas", "Rico", "Max", "Bastiaan", "Eugune"]; // Names array


function checkNames(names) {
var f = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    f.push(substring(names[i],0,1));
    }
return f;
}

var result_array = checkNames(names); // Filtered Array that will hold your single letters
```

Comment: This is an overly complicated way of doing when one could simply use `string.charAt(0)`.

Comment: @NicolasGarnier Just because there is another solution, does not mean this one is overly complicated. Agreed, string.chatAt(0), seems a better solution.